# Bootstrap. Img-response overflow on large screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Looks like pretty common usecase, but I couldn't find the answer.

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron my-jumbotron">
    <img class="img-responsive" src=
    {{'https://static.pexels.com/photos/2232/vegetables-italian-pizza-
    restaurant.jpg'}}>
</div>
```

On mobile image scales perfectly:

[image]

But on large screen it doesn't:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your `css` too ?

Comment: @kravisingh no additional CSS, only Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0):

I limited `max-width` for medium and larger devices adding this to CSS:

```
/********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .img-responsive {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
```